# Basement toilet drainage

Tags: plumbing

Will a basement toilet suck dry if sitting directly over the sewer line when the upstairs toilet is flushed or does it need to be offset?

Answer (score 6):

It needs to be properly vented. Over the line or offset sideways is not the issue.